# В проекте Laravel 5.2 запустить сиды

Tags: php, laravel

В проекте
Laravel  5.2.45
Пароли прописаны в файле
database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Admin;
use App\User;
use App\Role;
use App\Permission;
use App\Insurer;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
      $admin = Role::create(array(
        'name' => '...',
        'display_name' => '...',
        'type' => '...'
      ));

...

Admin::create(array(
  'name' => 'name',
  'email' => 'name@gmail.com',
  'password' => 'pass',
  'role_id' => $admin->id));
```

А как их правильно запустить ?

Спасибо!

---

Выполнив команду(в линуксовой консоле) получаю ошибку доступа

```
$ sass --watch  resources/assets/sass/app.scss:/assets/css/app.css 
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /assets/css/app.css
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Под рутом я выполнял :

```
 sudo chmod -R 777  /project_path/
```

Не помогает...

Если выполнить под рутом и внести изменнения то получаю Вывод :

```
root@serge-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/jaraujom/Medifin# sudo chmod -R 777  /_wwwroot/jaraujom/
root@serge-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/jaraujom/Medifin# sass --watch  resources/assets/sass/app.scss:/assets/css/app.css 
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
      write /assets/css/app.css
      write /assets/css/app.css.map
>>> Change detected to: resources/assets/sass/app.scss
      write /assets/css/app.css
      write /assets/css/app.css.map
>>> Change detected to: resources/assets/sass/app.scss
      write /assets/css/app.css
      write /assets/css/app.css.map
```

При этом файлов app.css и app.css.map ни в /public/assets/css/  ни в других подкаталогах не нашел...

При этом в resources/assets/sass/app.scss есть 55 определений вида :

```
@import “filename”;
```

...

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: php artisan db:seed

Answer (score 1):

В корневой директории проекта в консоли `db:seed` или `db:seed --class=DatabaseSeeder`

Comment: Спасибо помогло
Но запустив сайт у меня куча ошибок вида файл /assets/css/app.css не найден

При этом есть файл /resources/assets/sass/app.scss
Мне нужно выполнить публикацию ?Как ?

Comment: Вам необходим компилятор SASS в CSS. Грубо говоря сейчас у вас есть SASS файл, в котором содержатся инструкции для генерации CSS. Компилируете, располагаете где вам нужно и всё готово

Comment: Про sass->css я в курсе
но в 5.4/5.5 это делалась автоматом
Должен ли я выполнить команду вида :
 sass --watch  static/scss/default/admin/style.scss:static/css/default/admin/style.css  
 
 Для всех scss/js файлов?

Comment: Да, если автоматически не делает, то пробуйте таким образом

Comment: Попробую . Это уже существующий проект. Если это делается автоматичекски где это можно поискать?

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел файл gulpfile.js:

```
 var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('sass', function (){
    gulp.src(['resources/assets/sass/app.scss'])
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'expanded'
    }))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css/'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src(['resources/assets/vendor/**/*']).pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets'));
    gulp.src(['resources/assets/js/**/*']).pipe(uglify()).pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/js'));
})

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'scripts']);
```

Его как-то нужно запусать/инициировать?